# Setting environment variables by prompt instead of in command line

Tags: bash, variable, interactive

Is there a way for setting an environment variable in `bash` such that its value is not passed directly after `=` but is prompted for separately? For example, something akin to `$ TEST=<` (syntax does not actually work) instead of `$ TEST=test`.

Comment: `read -p "prompt" TEST` ?  (the `-p "prompt"` is optional)

Comment: @StephenHarris Excellent. If you want to turn your comment into an answer I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen [answered in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304740/setting-environment-variables-by-prompt-instead-of-in-command-line#comment535287_304740), shells that adhere to the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) will have a way to read input into a variable. [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) includes several extra flag to the read built-in command, none of which you need for your situation:

```
read TEST
```

will leave your terminal waiting for you to enter a line of input, which will be assigned to the TEST variable.